# How to install awning on siding

Tags: siding

I need to attach a 13 ft retractable awning onto my siding. (2) vertical ~ 3" thick gutters 10 ft apart are blocking it. Cannot re-route them. Thinking of mating (2) 2x6 PT wood and  attached it to siding. What is the best method to mate and attach them?

Comment: 3" thick "gutters" or downspouts. Pictures of where you want to mount it may help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @PlatinumGoose is right: we'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.